# Nothing happens when CI form submitted

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter-3

I have a form that is meant to collect Doctors information and store it in a MySQL table for a directory of doctors. I have other forms on the site that do other things. I am very new to Codeignitor and to OOP, but I seem stumped here as everytime I submit the form, it just reloads the form, and the data I filled in is gone. There are no error message in the form from validation. I did test, and it seems like in my controller, the if `($this->form_validation->run())` condition is not triggering as a `print_r($this->input->post());` run in that section does not trigger.

Below is my code /

CONTROLLER Form Validation:

```
public function add_doctor_val()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sname', 'Surname of Doctor', 'required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dr_field', 'Type of Doctor', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('town', 'City / Town / Village', 'required|alpha');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('postal_code', 'Postal / Zip Code', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tel  ', 'Telephone Number', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('web', 'website', 'valid_url');


        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {


            $user_id = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();


            $dr_info = array(
                'user' => $user_id,
                'sname' => $this->input->post('sname'),
                'dr_field' => $this->input->post('dr_field'),
                'country' => $this->input->post('country'),
                'town' => $this->input->post('town'),
                'postal_code' => $this->input->post('postal_code'),
                'tel' => $this->input->post('tel'),
                'web' => $this->input->post('web'),
                'review' => $this->input->post('review')



            );



            $this->db->insert('dr_dir', $dr_info);

            $this->success_pin();
        } else {
            $this->add_doctor();
        }
    }
```

THE FORM:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0 ">
    <?php
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        redirect('auth/login');
    } elseif ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        ?>
        <h1>Add Doctor to Directory</h1>

        <div id="map"></div>
        <form method="post" action="<?= base_url('index.php/forms/add_doctor_val'); ?>">
            <br />

            <p>Having a list of knowledgebal doctors is a vital tool for any AlphaGal sufferer. If you have a doctor who has taken the time to learn about AlphaGal and it's treatment, please fill in the form below</p>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php

                    echo form_label('Surname of Doctor', 'sname');
                    echo form_error('sname');
                    echo form_input('sname', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Type of Doctor', 'dr_field');
                    echo form_error('dr_field');
                    echo "<br />";
                    ?>

                    <select class="form-control" name="dr_field">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($doctors as $row) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $row->id . '">' . $row->field . '</option>' . "\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Country', 'country');
                    echo form_error('country');
                    echo "<br />";
                    ?>

                    <select class="form-control" name="country">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($countries as $row) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $row->country_iso_code . '">' . $row->country_name . '</option>' . "\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('City / Town / Village', 'town');
                    echo form_error('town');
                    echo form_input('town', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Postal / Zip Code', 'postal_code');
                    echo form_error('postal_code');
                    echo form_input('postal_code', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Telephone Number', 'tel');
                    echo form_error('tel');
                    echo form_input('tel', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Email', 'email');
                    echo form_error('email');
                    echo form_input('email', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Website', 'web');
                    echo form_error('web');
                    echo form_input('web', '', 'class="form-control"');
                    ?>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <?php
                    echo form_label('Leave a review', 'review');
                    echo form_error('review');
                    echo form_textarea('review', '', 'class="form-control"')
                    ?>
                </div>

            </div>



            <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'class="btn btn-primary btn-sm-15 btn-block"'); ?>
    </div>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have removed the validation, and it works. I have looked through the validation rules and syntax and cannot find the error

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, even though I do now know why:

This line here is throwing the whole script without error:

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">', '</div>');
```

The only thing that I can think of is that it was referenced twice